# I want to set CustomText in java how to do this?

Tags: android, text

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView txtview=new TextView(this);
    txtview.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   CustomTextView ct=new CustomTextView(this);


    txtview.setText(ct.setTypeface(tf));
    ll.addView(txtview);

//        here i want to set Custom Text
//        here i want to custom style of text in other class

     txtview.setText("Text");  


    setContentView(ll);
}



}

//    ohter class of text style

public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Log.e("Tag", "AttributeSet with style");
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.e("Tag", "AttributeSet");
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    Log.e("Tag", "context");
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
            getResources().getAssets(), "COMICATE.TTF");
    super.setTypeface(typeface);
}

}
```

Comment: What kind of functionality you want to add in your CustomTextView?

Answer (score 0):

Because your CustomTextView class extends TextView, you can use all method declare in TextView.
So, ct.setText("your text here") should work.
And make sure add your custom textview into your layout

Answer (score 0):

From seeing your code what I understood is at line `txtview.setText(ct.setTypeface(tf));` you got compile time error.
So change your code like

```
ct.setTypeface(tf);
ct.setText("Your text");
ll.addView(ct);
```